# 'open' statement in Perl splits path having spaces - how to read a file with spaces in path?

Tags: windows, path, perl

I've been banging my head against this same wall for 48 hours.  How do you pass a command line argument to Perl so that when Perl has the opportunity to open the file, it properly handles the Windows-style spaces that occur in a) directories or b) file names:

```
# open( PRELIM, "\"$ifile\"") or die "Cannot open $ifile";
# open( PRELIM, '\"$ifile\"') or die "Cannot open $ifile";
## Both these lines cannot deal with a space present in the path:
# open PRELIM, $ifile or print "\n* Couldn't open ${ifile}\n\n" && return;
# $ifile = qq($ifile);  Doesn't help, still leaves the file as if it was 'two' files
#
  # Quotes around $ifile do no good either
open( PRELIM, $ifile) or die "Cannot open $ifile"
```

Generally, the above line is correct until there is a space present in the variable '$ifile'.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html hinted the following might help,  but it didn't
sysopen(FH, $path, O_RDONLY);

Comment: `my @stupidString = split( / /, $ifile);
$ifile = join(' ', @stupidString)`

Comment: Above code, still, does nothing to rehabilitate the bad-acting spaces in the variable used in 'open'.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. I just ran the following command: `perl -e 'my $f = $ARGV[0]; open(my $fh, $f) or die "cannot open $f: $@\n"; while (<$fh>) { print "$f: $_"; };' 'C:\cygwin\tmp\fn with space'` and it prints the contents of the file just fine.  My guess is that you're not *setting* the value of `$ifile` correctly.

Comment: By the way, do switch to the three-argument form of open: `open( my $prelim, '<', $ifile)`

Answer (score 4):

To pass a command-line argument as a single argument that also contains spaces, enclose it within quotation marks.  For example:

perl script-name.pl "C:\My path with spaces"

This will cause the parameter to be handled as a single word.

(Within your code, if you're hard-coding back-slashes, then you need to double them up since "\" is a special meta-character, hence "\" will be converted to "\" at compile-time.)

Comment: Randolf is right, with Perl on Windows all you have to do is pass the file path and name in quotes for `open` to work, but some Perl modules complain with Windows style paths. `$filename =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;` will escape backslashes and `$file =~ s/\ /\\ /g;` will escape spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You want the three argument form of [`open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

```
open(PRELIM, '<', $ifile) or die "Cannot open $ifile"    # For reading
open(PRELIM, '>', $ifile) or die "Cannot open $ifile"    # For writing
```

Always use the three argument version of `open()` to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Perl, but I was able to look around and I found a forum post that may help you: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=376686&page=567

They are discussing the exact issue you are having and the first person in there suggested using single quotes instead of double to use a string literal so 
$DIRECTORY = 'C:\Documents and Settings';

instead of

```
$DIRECTORY = "C:\Documents and Settings";
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Vert, If I were setting the variable inside the Perl script, the single quotes DO work.  However, I'm passing the variable in as $ARG[1] (or something like that) from the command line. So I need to find a way to achieve similar/same effect on an incoming string.  Perhaps I should find a way to 'escape' the space? Maybe split the ARG[1] on the space(s) and join them together with some special trick?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any Perl experience. The only other thing I can think of is having users type the actual argument in as a string literal for you (ie program.pl 'c:\in\this directory\') or see if perl can cast the arg as a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are also not using any reserved characters in your filename either.

I made that mistake of using a question mark as a default field value which only materialised in the filename as an issue !

Answer (score 0):

```perl
my $rootDir = shift @ARGV;
$rootDir =~ s/\p{space}/\\ /g;
```